# Disabling Html control

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I got an aspx page with HTML controls,Based on the button click function I want to change the visibility of controls.If user clicks on EDIT,I want to disable the controls otherwise (NEW) enable the controls.Please suggest me in doing this.

Comment: I want to disable controls on EDIT and enable on NEW please....

Comment: to disable `$('input, select', '.FormSectionContent').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny,Thanks for responding.But I want to disable only the dropdowns while the user clicks on EDIT button.and when he clicks on NEW all the controls should enable.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to all your dropdowns (ex: class="test"), then onclick, enable or disable. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KPfvw/

```
$("#btnNew").click(function() {
    $(".test").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("#btnEdit").click(function() {
    $(".test").prop("disabled", true);
});
```